# Как вызвать friend-функцию шаблона (и правильно ли она объявлена внутри шаблона)

Tags: c++

**Так выглядит шаблон:**

```
template<class TreeElement, class Comparator, class Operation>
class AVLTree { ... };
```

Так выглядит декларация дружественной функции в публичном пространстве класса:

```
template<class A, class B, class C >
friend AVLTree<A, B, C> createEmptyAVLTree(int n);
```

**Так я пытаюсь вызвать в другом файле:**

```
AVLTree::createEmptyTree();
```

Но пишет `is not a member` и `could not be resolved`.

Что неверно сделано ?

Comment: Для начала - вы точно объявляете `createEmptyAVLTree`, а вызываете `createEmptyTree`? и еще - тут предлагалась правка, что вы вызываете `AVLTree<Post, postByLikesFunc, emptyFunc>::createEmptyTree();` - это и в самом деле так, или нет?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Функции-друзья, объявленные только в теле класса, не являются членами класса, и не находятся в пространстве имен класса.

Единственный способ вызвать такую функцию - это использовать поиск имен по типам аргументов (ADL). Для этого надо, чтобы один из аргументов был связан с типом класса:

```
struct X {
    friend void f() {}  // Эту функцию никак не вызвать
    friend void g(X const&) {}  // ОК, эта функцию может быть найдена
};

int main() {
    X x;
    g(x);  // Вызов функции с поиском по типу аргумента
}
```

Либо объявите `createEmptyAVLTree` вне класса, либо сделайте ее статической.